# How can I map a shared folder from my container on Mac?

Tags: macos, samba, docker, macos-sierra, container

I have a folder insider a Docker container that is shared through Samba. I can map this folder on Windows without problem running something like:

```
net use z: \\vm_ip\folder
```

In the case above, `z:` is the drive that I created with the content from the shared folder.

How could I map that same folder on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Add it as a login item (according to http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/69865-mount-smb-network-drive-permanently/)

1. Mount drive in **Finder**
2. Go to **System Preferences** > **Accounts** > **Login Items**
3. Add this drive in the list of objects as if it were an application